# Is there anyway to know when the wave function collapse?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-entanglement, wavefunction-collapse

If we get 2 entangled particles and move them away from each other, is there a way to put one of them is some kind of "sensor" that would tell if the entangled particle have been measured?
If yes, how does one function?
If not, how do we know that the measure of one did collapse the other?

Comment: Wave function collapse is just a concept in the context of an interpretation of QM. It does not actually happen.

Comment: @my2cts so what ensures that the measure of one made the other be out of super position?

Comment: What do you mean by one of the particles to be "out of superposition"?

Comment: I mean if I got 2 entangled particles in super position, when one break out of super position the other will too right?

Comment: All QM tells you is the probability of measurement outcomes on the two particles, which will be correlated.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of entangled particles, they are usually separated so that a signal cannot pass from one to the other.

The wave function is an expression of the probability for the result of a measurement. Probability is a human assessment of likelihood. Since Alice and Bob have different information, it is natural that they assign different probabilities, and consequently different wavefunctions. When Alice performs a measurement of one particle, entanglement ensures that Alice's wavefunction for both particles collapses. This does not affect Bob's wave function in any way. There is no way he can know whether Alice has performed a measurement. Only later, when the results of measurement are brought together, is a correlation found between the measurements of Alice and Bob.

Comment: So basically there is no way of knowing if it was Alice or Bob measure that collapsed the wave function?

Comment: They each collapse their own wave function, and have no effect on the wave function of the other.